# 1004 Error for Validation range with (normally) good referencing

Tags: vba, excel

Already read some others questions with 1004 error and problem of referencing. I tried to apply it to my code but I still have this error. It works when I activate the sheet first and I select `range_list`but i would like to avoid this. Error is on line `.Add`

```
Set tableau_scores = wsParam.Range(wsParam.Cells(3, 1), wsParam.Cells(derniere_ligne_scores, 1))

For i = 0 To nombre_sousclasse_actif(numero_actif - 1, 0) - 1
    Set range_liste = wsScores.Range(wsScores.Cells(derniere_ligne + 1, 2 + i), wsScores.Cells(derniere_ligne + 1, 2 + i))    
    With range_liste.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='" & wsParam.Name & "'!" & tableau_scores.Address
    End With
    range_liste.Value = 0    
Next i
```

Thanks !

**EDIT** : It works when I am on the sheet "Param" but not on the sheet "Scores"

**EDIT 2 :**  I really don't understand, i create a new module, i put this code and it works...

```
Sub testliste()
    Dim tableau_scores As Range
    Dim range_liste As Range

    Set tableau_scores = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Param").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Param").Cells(3, 1), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Param").Cells(7, 1))
    Set range_liste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scores").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scores").Cells(9, 2), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scores").Cells(9, 2))

    With range_liste.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Param").Name & "'!" & tableau_scores.Address
    End With
    range_liste.Value = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Try writing `Debug.print wsParam.Name, tableau_scores.Address` before the error line and see what happens in the immediate window.

Comment: It says `Param         $A$3:$A$7` which are the good sheet name and the good range for the list

Comment: does it fail at I=0 or any other value within the loop

Comment: also, why not apply to the whole range?

Comment: At any value. I just edited my post, it works when I'm on the sheet "Param" but not on the sheet "Scores". What do you mean by apply to the whole range ?

Comment: what is `nombre_sousclasse_actif`

Comment: It's a (n,2) matrix which memorizes, for each family, how many sub_families there are

Comment: By any chance, is the sheet locked or something?

Comment: And write `Debug.print range_liste.address` exactly before the error line.

Comment: The sheet "Param" is protected but with the mode "UserInterfaceOnly:=True" and i unprotected it before my test. the debug.print says `$B$9`which is the good range where i want my list for the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: does hard coding `'Param'!$A$3:$A$7` go through?

Comment: Unfortunately not !

Comment: set up a new sheet with just 1,2,3 or what ever and use this as the list, hardcoded, see if that works, then try this is a newly created worksheet, but with the same param references.  It's hard to debug, non screen-side :)

Comment: So with 1,2,3 in another new sheet it doesnt work. But if i create a new module, a new sheet and i try to create a list on a cell of this new sheet with value from "Param", it works hardcoded and with `Formula1:="='" & wsParam.Name & "'!" & tableau_scores.Address`. Thanks for trying to help btw !

Comment: I edit my main post, i put the same part of code on a new module and it works